# data-autodividers=true not rendering dividers when creating list items dynamically for a listview

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I'm trying to add list items to an unordered list that is defined with "data-autodividers='true'" in the HTML  My question is, why aren't the autodividers showing up?

HTML:

```
<ul id="places" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="true"></ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$.each(json, function(key,val) {
    var html = "<li>"+val.city+"</li>";
    $('#places').append(html);
    $("#places li").trigger('create');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, around 364 days later, I incurred in this question myself.

Solution from http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/lists/docs-lists.html:

> **Updating lists:**
>   If you add items to a listview, you'll need to call the `refresh()` method on it to update the styles and create any nested lists that are added. For example:
>
> `$('#mylist').listview('refresh');`
>
> **Note** that the refresh() method only affects new nodes appended to a list. This is done for performance reasons. Any list items already enhanced will be ignored by the refresh process. This means that if you change the contents or attributes on an already enhanced list item, these won't be reflected. If you want a list item to be updated, replace it with fresh markup before calling refresh.

There's a good example for listview with dynamic content and autodividers here http://jsfiddle.net/MauriceG/bwdVh/.

See [how to create auto list dividers when dynamically creating a list in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527014/how-to-create-auto-list-dividers-when-dynamically-creating-a-list-in-jquery-mobi) for a similar question with way~ better answer.